# How to change row color depending on criteria?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Apps Script and need some help figuring out how to code my spreadsheet. The spreadsheet is populated by a user submitting a form. I would like for the row color to change depending on the response of a certain column. Here is what I have so far:

```
function colorRow(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Requests");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  // will get the row
  var row = range.getRow();

  // get the cell value to compare
  var cellValue = range.getValue()

  if(cellValue == "Cancel Interpreter Request"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 0, 0);
  }
  else if(cellValue == "Next Day Interpreter Request"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(201, 218, 248);
  }
  else if(cellValue == "Update Existing Interpreter Request"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 0);
  }
  else if(cellValue == "Same Day Request"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(106, 168, 79);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
}

function onSubmit(e){
  colorRow();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`getActiveSpreadsheet()` is applicable only when you are editing the spreadsheet. When a user submits a form, there is no active spreadsheet. Use `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` instead.

Also, `getDataRange()` gives you the range of the entire sheet. If you are looking for the row to which the recent form submission was entered, use `e.range`
Something like

```
function colorRow(dataRange){

  // get the cell value to compare
  var cellValue = dataRange.getValue()

  if(cellValue == "Cancel Interpreter Request"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 0, 0);
  }
  else if(cellValue == "Next Day Interpreter Request"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(201, 218, 248);
  }
  else if(cellValue == "Update Existing Interpreter Request"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 0);
  }
  else if(cellValue == "Same Day Request"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(106, 168, 79);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
}

function onSubmit(e){
  colorRow(e.range);
}
```